# How do two equations multiply left by left equals right by right?

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

```
eq1=x+2y==9
eq2=3x+2y==10
```

How to operate the multiplication of two equations to obtain:

```
(x+2y)(3x+2y)==90
```

Simplify to obtain:

```
3x^2+8xy+4y^2==90
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I much prefer

```
MultiplySides[eq1, eq2] //Expand
```

to BobHanlon's otherwise fine solution.  It also generalizes quite nicely to `AddSides[]`.

Answer (score 9):

```
Thread[eq1 eq2, Equal]
(* (x + 2 y) (3 x + 2 y) == 90 *)

% // Expand
(* 3 x^2 + 8 x y + 4 y^2 == 90 *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq1 = x + 2 y == 9;
eq2 = 3 x + 2 y == 10;

eq3 = Equal @@ Times @@ (List @@@ {eq1, eq2})

(* (x + 2 y) (3 x + 2 y) == 90 *)

eq4 = eq3 // ExpandAll

(* 3 x^2 + 8 x y + 4 y^2 == 90 *)
```