# How do two equations divide left by left equals right by right?

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

such as 1:

```
eq1=x+y==3
eq2=x+2y==7
```

get the result:

```
(x+y)/(x+2y)==3/7
```

such as 2:

```
eq3=x^2-y^2==9
eq4=x-y==3
```

get the result:

```
x+y==3
```

such as 3:

The parameters a and c are both greater than 0

```
eq5=((x+c)^2+y^2)-((x-c)^2+y^2)==4 c x
eq6=Sqrt[(x+c)^2+y^2]+Sqrt[(x-c)^2+y^2]==2a
```

get the result:

```
Sqrt[(x+c)^2+y^2]-Sqrt[(x-c)^2+y^2]==2 c x/a
```

to David

The second and the third scenario did not achieve the desired result

[image]

```
eq3 = x^2 - y^2 == 9
eq4 = x - y == 3
DivideSides[eq3, eq4, Assumptions -> {x - y != 0}]
```

```
eq5 = ((x + c)^2 + y^2) - ((x - c)^2 + y^2) == 4 c x
eq6 = Sqrt[(x + c)^2 + y^2] + Sqrt[(x - c)^2 + y^2] == 2 a
DivideSides[eq5, eq6, Assumptions -> {a > 0, c > 0}]
```

Adding it doesn't work either

Comment: `DivideSides` accepts `Assumptions` option, please read the document carefully. And please put a bit more effort in adding proper tags to your question.

Comment: Just similar to using `Expand` in your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/283845/how-do-two-equations-multiply-left-by-left-equals-right-by-right), `Simplify`/`FullSimplify`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

div[eq1_, eq2_] := Equal @@ Divide @@ List @@@ {eq1, eq2}

eq1 = x + y == 3;
eq2 = x + 2 y == 7;

div[eq1, eq2]

(* (x + y)/(x + 2 y) == 3/7 *)

eq3 = x^2 - y^2 == 9;
eq4 = x - y == 3;

Simplify@div[eq3, eq4]

(* x + y == 3 *)

eq5 = ((x + c)^2 + y^2) - ((x - c)^2 + y^2) == 4 c x;
eq6 = Sqrt[(x + c)^2 + y^2] + Sqrt[(x - c)^2 + y^2] == 2 a;

Assuming[a > 0 && c > 0, FullSimplify@div[eq5, eq6]]

(* Sqrt[(c + x)^2 + y^2] == (2 c x)/a + Sqrt[(c - x)^2 + y^2] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

As with `MultiplySides`:

```
DivideSides[eq1, eq2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
Thread[Unevaluated@Divide[##], Equal] &[eq1, eq2]

Thread[Unevaluated@Divide[##], Equal] &[eq3, eq4] // Map@Simplify

Thread[Unevaluated@Divide[##], Equal] &[eq5, eq6] // Map@FullSimplify
```

Comment: Can you generalize this method to two equations adding, subtracting, and multiplying simultaneously? thank you!

Comment: @csn899 I don't think you are ready for evaluation control. Take a look at `ApplySides`. When reading the document you should always check those in **See also** section at the end of document page.